# How can I make a delay in a Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, delay

I have a `JFrame` and some labels I want to display these labels one by one (but delay time) when I press a button. I tried using this code:

```
        label_1.setVisible(1000);
        Thread.sleep(time);
        label_2.setVisible(1000);
        Thread.sleep(time);
        label_3.setVisible(1000);
        Thread.sleep(time);
        label_4.setVisible(1000);
```

But the application waits the time of time (4000 ms) then display all labels at once.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. Use a Swing `Timer`. to display each label in turn. See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code which use swing timer class which perform delay to visible the labels on frame.You just create a `ActionListener` object that holds code that you want to perform in delay and also **base criteria** for stopping the timer.And then create a Timer Object like `new Timer(Delay,ActionListenerObject)`

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
public class LabelDelay {
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label1;
    JLabel label2;
    JLabel label3;
    JLabel label4;
    JPanel contentPane;
    Timer timer;
    int count=0;

    public LabelDelay() {
       JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
       frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4));

       label1 = new JLabel("Label1");
       contentPane.add(label1);

       label2 = new JLabel("Label2");
       contentPane.add(label2);

       label3 = new JLabel("Label3");
       contentPane.add(label3);

       label4 = new JLabel("Label4");
       contentPane.add(label4);

       frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
       frame.pack();

       label1.setVisible(false);
       label2.setVisible(false);
       label3.setVisible(false);
       label4.setVisible(false);


       ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          switch(count) {
            case 0:
              label1.setVisible(true);
              break;
            case 1:
              label2.setVisible(true);
              break;
            case 2:
              label3.setVisible(true);
              break;
            case 3:
              label4.setVisible(true);
              break;
            case 4:
              timer.stop();//base criteria
              break;
          }
          count++;    
        }
      };      
       frame.setVisible(true);
       timer = new Timer(1000, action);
       timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      new LabelDelay();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks sir for guiding to how give an answer

Answer (score 0):

Also you could simply use four `Timer` objects that starts one after another

```
Timer timer4 = new Timer(500, e -> {
    label_4.setVisible(true);
});

Timer timer3 = new Timer(500, e -> {
    label_3.setVisible(true);
    timer4.start();
});

Timer timer2 = new Timer(500, e -> {
    label_2.setVisible(true);
    timer3.start();
});

Timer timer1 = new Timer(500, e -> {
    label_1.setVisible(true);
    timer2.start();
});
timer1.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel labels[] = {
            new JLabel("Label 1"),
            new JLabel("Label 2"),
            new JLabel("Label 3"),
            new JLabel("Label 4")
    };

    private SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(4000);
                publish(i);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            chunks.stream().forEach(i -> labels[i].setVisible(true));
        }
    };

    public TestFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Test Frame");
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        Arrays.stream(labels).forEach(label -> {
            label.setVisible(false);
            panel.add(label);
        });

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                worker.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```